# Test about the NTFS file entry

Tags: file, operating-system, filesystems, ntfs

I'd be glad if you could help me with a test based on NTFS system. I've been trying to find the correct answer but now I feel even more stuck. Here's a close translation of the test:

```
Entry in a directory of the NTFS file system contains:
a. a reference (a link) to the index junction (node?);
b. a reference (a link) to the first cluster on the disk;
c. a reference (a link) to the file allocation table;
d. a reference (a link) to the chain of clusters on the disk.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a. a reference (a link) to the index junction (node?);